# mysql: Get combination of data from multiple table by passing multiple value

Tags: mysql, database, sails.js, mysql-workbench, rdbms

In my DB. I have three tables Category, Location and classification.

I have some value in array for every column

```
 location:['delhi','mumbai','goa','chennai']
 Category:['Teacher','Student','Managment']
 classification:['expert','normal']
```

Now I want to fetch the combination of data from the table.

I'm using a stored procedure for this.

Previously I have only one location, one category and one classification so I'm using this:

```
FROM user u1, serviceprovider s1, city c1 
WHERE s1.userId = u1.id 
  AND c1.cityId = s1.city
  AND s1.serviceProviderId IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT serviceprovidecategoryr_cl AS serviceProviderId 
       FROM Db.serviceprovider_cl__serviceproviderclassification_classification t1
       INNER JOIN Db.location_servicelocation__serviceprovider_locationid t2 ON t1.serviceprovider_cl = t2.serviceprovider_locationId
       INNER JOIN Db.category_serviceprovidercategory__serviceprovider_category t3 ON t2.serviceprovider_locationId = t3.serviceprovider_category
       WHERE 
           t1.serviceproviderclassification_classification IN 
              (SELECT serviceProviderClassificationId 
               FROM serviceProviderClassification sp 
               WHERE sp.name = classification)
           AND t2.location_serviceLocation IN 
               (SELECT locationId 
                FROM location 
                WHERE shortAddress = location)
           AND t3.category_serviceProviderCategory IN 
               (SELECT categoryId 
                FROM category 
                WHERE categoryName = category)
);
END
```

but now I'm getting the multiple values so how to modify this stored procedure?

If there is any other good way for doing this.

Please help...